# Django error for image upload to S3 bucket using Rest Post Request

Tags: django, rest, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am learning and trying how to upload file in Django using Post method, and here I encountered two errors for the same code

1. Postman uploading via Post->form-data error is **{'bookName': [ErrorDetail(string='This field is required.', code='required')], 'bookCover': [ErrorDetail(string='No file was submitted.', code='required')]}**
2. Uploading via web-based Django Framework :
   **{
   "bookCover": [
   "The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form."
   ]
   }**

**Serializer.py**

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ['bookName', 'bookCover']  # '__all__' for all
```

**View.py**

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def book_list(request):
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        # user = request.user
        # if not user:
        #     return Response(status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)
        serializer = BookSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        print(serializer.errors)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**Url.py**

```
path('books/', book_list)
```

I am using the same URL for post and get request.
books/ and books/?name=Book1 get request
books/ for post

I am trying to upload books image to s3 using post request. If I remove the image field then its working fine for web-based API it's creating the book object but for the postman, it just gives error even if I try the raw data instead of form-data.

**for web-based Post request:**

```
{
    "bookName": "Book8",
    "bookCover": null // here should I use "/pathto local file" or 'path to file' or 'aws file path'
}
```

Comment: Is bookCover defined as an ImageField or FileField? Show your model definition. As for how to upload file from JS, check here https://usefulangle.com/post/67/pure-javascript-ajax-file-upload-showing-progess-percent

Comment: It's defined as ImageField. Though I have tried to do that using class-based API view and it worked. Idk why it's not working the function-based view.

Comment: You have to add a multipart parser to parse the form data

Comment: parser_classes = (FileUploadParser, MultiPartParser). I have added this in class-based view and it's working fine. Thanks for the suggestion.